# Spring Boot Rest API Enumerate some Java types

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I am building Spring Boot webflux REST API functionality that needs to work with data containing few Java type's (let's consider String, Integer, Double for example) information as part of JSON request/responses. Attribute representing Java type must be persistable inside mongodb as well (should not be problem once JSON can work with such attribute). I have following model class and type enumeration which is used by REST API to serialize/deserialize JSON message's.

```
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "id")
@Document(collection = "core_scheme")
@JsonDeserialize(builder = SchemeModel.Builder.class)
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true, setterPrefix = "with")
public class SchemeModel {

    @Id
    private final String id;

    @Field(name = "userId") private final String userId;
    @Field(name = "date") private final String creationDate;
    @Field(name = "properties") private final Map<String, SchemeTypes> properties;
}
```

```
public enum SchemeTypes {
    INTEGER, STRING, DOUBLE
}
```

Serialization and deserialization work's well. Now the problem is that when i want to resolve real Java type's stored inside `Map<String, SchemeTypes> properties` map i need to do mapping similar to this (just abstraction not real code):

```
SchemeTypes.INTEGER => Java Integer class  
SchemeTypes.STRING => Java String class  
SchemeTypes.DOUBLE => Java Double class
```

Is there any more simple way to represent Java type's stored inside model class and used within serialized/deserialized JSON file's so i can directly use it to deduce Java type without additional validation that it's valid Java type. For example if type's enumarated inside mentioned enum would have exactly same naming as real Java type's i could do following without any mapping:

```
public void deduceClass(SchemeTypes type) {
    Class myClass = Class.forName(type.toString());
}
```

Note that i am looking for a solution which would work out of the box (i don't have to validate type's provided by user). If such solution would be harder to implement as mentioned mapping i will stick with mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you weren't saving this entity I could say you can actually directly map the SchemeTypes into corresponding class like following

```
public enum SchemeTypes {
    INTEGER(Integer.class), STRING(String.class), DOUBLE(Double.class);

    private final Class clazz;

    private SchemeTypes(Class clazz){
       this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    
    public Class getClazz(){
       return clazz;
    }
}
```

But as you are saving this it could cause some issue to deserialize.
Maybe you can save not the SchemaType instance directly but just the name of enum to overcome this like following

```
private final Map<String, String> properties;
```

and find the corresponding clazz value with a static method on this class like following

```
public static Class findClazzFor(String schemeTypeName){
       return SchemeTypes.valueOf(schemeTypeName).getClazz();
    }
```

Nevertheless I think cleanest solution would be keeping the SchemeType class instance mapping somewhere as a one-to-one map. And retrieve the corresponding class for provided schemeType as in the getClazz method above.

Comment: Yep, that enum you have poste is exactly what i wanted to achieve. I knew i have seen something like i just couldnt remeber it. I will do some test's if enum Like that is persistable by spring in mongodb. Since i am using webflux there is no such technology as Hibernate but if such enum is serializable/deserializable which i think it is because Basic enum's are and your are only specifying type for each enumeration (that's java code which should resolve type) this should work. Please feel free to upvote question as its not common question according to spring Rest API's.

Comment: I can verify that your suggested Enum work's well, can be serialized/deserialized by Jackson and is persist-able in mongodb with spring boot. This is therefore valid answer to my question and since no mapping to corresponding Java classes is required with such Enum (thank's to Java class information stored directly inside Enum) i mark this answer as accepted.